# filter images from webpage based on size

Tags: php

i want to list all images from any particular webpage but want to list only those images whose size is biggger than 10kb .i am using this code to list the images which lists all images of that particular page but i dont want to list images whose size is less than 10 kb

```
$url="http://example.com";

$html = file_get_contents($url);

$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($html);

$tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');

foreach ($tags as $tag) {
   echo $tag->getAttribute('src');
}
```

Comment: Ok and what have you tried before?

Comment: @stony i tried getimagesize but it did not worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP has a `filesize()` function which returns the size in `bytes` and would be used as such:

```
echo "The file size in KB is ".(filesize('image.png')/1024);
```

The only problem is that it doesn't work with remote files.

So, you could:

1. Save each image to a temporary directory
2. Iterate through them and check the filesize
3. If the size is <10, delete it
4. List the remaining images

*Edit*

As Blowski has pointed out, as of PHP 5.0, it will work with some URL wrappers, so you should be fine.

*Edit 2*

Some sample code:

```
foreach ($tags as $tag) {
   if (file_exists($tag->getAttribute('src')) && filesize($tag->getAttribute('src')) >= 10240)
     echo $src;
   }
}
```

*Edit 3*

I did some more research, and found that `stat` is not supported by the [HTTP(S)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.http.php) protocol. Therefore, you **must** save the file to your own server for it to work.

*Edit 4*

Solution using `get_headers()` approach instead of `filesize()`.

```
foreach ($tags as $tag) {
   $data = get_headers($tag->getAttribute('src'));
   if(($data["Content-Length"]/1024)>=10){
     echo $src;
   }
}
```

Comment: `filesize()` should work with external URLs, since PHP 5.0 - http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.

Comment: @mihir yeah that's a really dodgy bit of the PHP documentation. It is supported, except it isn't. Looks like the `get_headers()` approach is the best.

Comment: @user1515503 apparently so. So, you can either use a) my method but temporarily save files to your server or b) use the `get_headers()` method.

Comment: @user1515503 I've updated it with working code using the `get_headers()` approach.

Comment: @mihir no output is coming please run this code once          <?php 
$url="http://www.santabanta.com/photos/amisha-patel/402186.htm";

$html = file_get_contents($url);

$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($html);

$tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');

foreach ($tags as $tag) {
$src = $tag->getAttribute('src');
   $data = get_headers($tag->getAttribute('src'));
   if(($data["Content-Length"]/1024)>=10){
     echo $data;
  
   }
}

?>

Comment: @user1515503 Here's some __even better__ code: [here](http://chopapp.com/#vbjgswze).

Comment: @mihir can wesave this output in database?????// when i am trying to save only first line is gettingsaved however echo gives perfect output

Comment: @user1515503 I would suggest making a new question for this. You would  need to provide the database type and the code that you are trying to use.

Comment: @mihir can i have ur email address plz

Comment: @mihir here is the link for new question please help  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11998895/storing-output-in-mysql

Answer (score 2):

Try this:-

```
$img = get_headers("http://static.adzerk.net/Advertisers/2564.jpg", 1);
$imgbit = $img["Content-Length"]/1024;

echo "The file size in KB is ".$imgbit;
```

Comment: Ok i think thats the best Answer ^^

Comment: @abid hussain can wesave this output in database?????// when i am trying to save only first line is gettingsaved however echo gives perfect output